# How can I parse through a text doc formatted like a quiz and make a list without using \n for every row and every question

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a .txt doc with multiple questions formatted like this:
1) question one:

a) answer 1

b) answer 2

c) answer 3

2) question 2:

etc...

How can i convert them into list so i can transform into a quiz not taking them manually like this:

questions = ["1) question one:\n a) answer 1\n b)answer 2\n c) answer 3\n\n", "2) question two:\n a) answer 1\n b) answer 2\n c) answer 3\n\n, etc]

Thank you!

I do have, this is what i managed so far with the quiz:

```
class Question:
    def __init__(self, prompt, answer):
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.answer = answer

question_prompts = ["What color are bananas?\n(a) red\n(b) black\n(c) yellow\n\n",]
answer_prompts = ['c','e','a','c']


questions = [
    Question(question_prompts[0],answer_prompts[0]),
    Question(question_prompts[1],answer_prompts[1]),
    Question(question_prompts[2],answer_prompts[2]),
    Question(question_prompts[3],answer_prompts[3])
    ]

def run_test(questions):
    score = 0
    for question in questions:
        answer = input(question.prompt)
        if answer == question.answer:
            score += 1
            print('Correct!')
        else:
            print('Wrong, the answer was ' + question.answer +'\n')

    print(" You got " + str(score) + "/" + str(len(questions)) + " correct")

run_test(questions)
```

i can open the file i tried with this to kinda sort the line:

```
fileinput = open('pyFile.txt', 'r')
qList = []
for line in fileinput:
     if line.startswith(('2','3','4','5')): 
         qList.append(line)
```

Comment: It helps to decompose the problem into different steps. Can you open a file? Can you scan through each line? Can you parse each line for the parts you care about? Do you have any code for what have you tried so far?

Comment: what i need is to take the line with the question and the other 5 lines with a,b,c,d,e from my text doc and put it in one element of a list with \n in it, then the second question in another element end so on

Answer (score 0):

Read line by line then:

```
import reprlib
def grep(pattern,lines,sep=")"):
    tmp_line=""
    for line in lines:

        try:
            pattern(line.split(sep)[0])
            yield tmp_line+"\n"
            tmp_line=""
        except:
            pass
        tmp_line+="\n"+line
    yield tmp_line

if __name__=="__main__":
    lines = ["1) question one:","a) answer 1","b) answer 2","c) answer 3","2) question 2:","a) Not an answer"]
    for x in grep(int,lines):
        if x is None or len(x) < 3:
            continue  ## first one will always be None
        print(repr(x)) ## one question with answers
        print("_______________") ## one question with answers
```

It will print:

> '\n1) question one:\na) answer 1\nb) answer 2\nc) answer 3\n'
>
> ---
>
> '\n2) question 2:\na) not an answer'
>
> ---